# How to get Purchased state of a managed productid in android in appbilling?

Tags: android

I am using market billing Dungeons example for inapp billing.Its working fine.But my problem is i purchased a product with reserved productid "android.test.purchased" and it displays in my product list,but if i uninstall my app and re-install iam not getting the product.How to get purchased items even if i uninstall and reinstall the app.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the market a RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS message. It is discussed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: iam getting result ok for any case,when i do this.Actually,what response should i get for purchased item???????

Comment: it should always return an ok result, but if you had purchased anything then i would expect the market to send you further transaction messages. Assuming you are using managed purchases, as the documentation says.